# Error "procedural assignment to a non-register result is not permitted"

Tags: verilog, vivado

I'm getting the error

> [Synth 8-2576] procedural assignment to a non-register result is not
>   permitted ["lpm_mult.v":29]

What am i doing wrong?

```
module lpm_mult (
    dataa, datab,     // multiplicand,multiplier
    sum,              // partial sum 
    clock,            // pipeline clock
    clken,            // clock enable
    aclr,             // asynch clear
    result            // product
);

input  clock;
input  clken;
input  aclr;
input  [31:0] dataa;
input  [31:0] datab;
input  [63:0] sum;
output [63:0] result;

always @ (clken or posedge clock) begin
    if (1==clken) begin
        assign result = dataa * datab;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are more issues then then giving error message. As others have already pointed out `result` should be defined as `output reg [63:0] result;`

The other issues will not generate a compiling error; they are generating incorrect behavior and are unsynthesizable. With the code:

> ```
> always @ (clken or posedge clock) begin
>     if (1==clken) begin
>         assign result = dataa * datab;
>     end
> end
> ```

- `clken` is asynchronous trigger; it should not be in the sensitivity list.
- An `assign` statement inside the always block is call a procedural continuous assignment. Once the assignment is triggered, it will be continuously and immediately updated on any change to `dataa` or `datab` (ignoring the conditions of `clken` and `clock`).

  - Note: IEEE is considering depreciating procedural continuous assignment, so in the future it will likely become illegal syntax. [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) C.4.2 *Procedural assign and deassign statements*:

    > The procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements can be a source of design errors and can be an impediment to tool implementation. The procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements do not provide a capability that cannot be done by another method that avoids these problems. Therefore, the procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements are on a deprecation list. In other words, a future revision of IEEE Std 1800 might not require support for these statements. This current standard still requires tools to support the procedural `assign` and `deassign` statements. However, users are strongly encouraged to migrate their code to use one of the alternate methods of procedural or continuous assignments.

    Regular continuous assignments (`assign` outside of procedural block) will remain as legal legal syntax.
    Verilog and SystemVerilog were officially merged by IEEE with IEEE Std 1800-2009.
- Synchronous logic should use non-blocking (`<=`) assignments. It is legal syntax to blocking (`=`) assignments in synchronous logic blocks, but is it not recommenced. Using blocking assignments in synchronous logic blocks may cause race conditions in the simulator resulting in behavioral mismatch between RTL and synthesized circuit.

  - Note: `assign` statements must use blocking assignments (non-blocking is illegal syntax).

Your code should look something line the following to compile and behave correctly in simulation:

```
...
output reg [63:0] result;

always @ (posedge clock) begin
    if (clken==1) begin
        result <= dataa * datab;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning to `result` inside an `always` block, which is not allowed, because `result` is a `wire`, not a `reg`.

Declare `result` as follows to make it work:

```
output reg [63:0] result;
```

Answer (score 3):

By default all input and output signals are 'wires'. Wires cannot be assigned in the procedural blocks.

```
output reg [63:0] result;
```

This should fix the error.