# Verilog (assign in always)

Tags: verilog

I came to know that we can use assign statements in procedural blocks(like in always), what  will be the difference in using "assign" inside always block and outside it(in concern with synthesized circuit). I mean when it is absolutely necessary to use assign in always?

Comment: Related questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/31472546/1959732 and
https://stackoverflow.com/q/23687172/1959732

Answer (score 6):

Never, `assign` keyword is for continuous assignment and it will generate combinatorial logic at synthesis. In fact, you can obtain the `assign` behaviour with an always block:

```
wire test;
//At all times, test equals input
assign test = input;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
reg test;
//Each time input changes(with the always@*), test takes its value
always@*
  test = input;
```

In `always` blocks, you should only use non-blocking assignment('<=') which are procedural assignments. Using blocking assignment is possible, however, you have to be sure to do what you want.

From [this thread](http://www.edaboard.com/thread248844.html):

> Two rules to live by that I know of no exceptions:
>
> 1. Always use blocking assignments for combinatorial or level-sensitive code, as well a clock assignments
> 2. Always use non-blocking assignments for variables that are written on a clock edge, and read on the same clock edge in another process.

Answer (score 3):

**assign** and corresponding **deassign** (in always blocks) are also called 'procedural continuous assighment' can be used in always blocks for specific purposes. In most cases this is non-synthesizable and I had never ran across its use.

an example:

```
   reg in1, in2, out;
   reg [1:0] select;

   always @* begin
      case (select)
        2'b01: assign out = in1;
        2'b10: assign out = in2;
        2'b11: deassign out;
      endcase // case (select)
   end
```

general recommendateion -- do not use it.