# Verilog:Procedural Continuous Assignment to register is not supported

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, quartus, procedural

```
    input [31:0] write_data;
    input [4:0]  write_reg;
    reg [31:0] registers [31:0];

always @(*) 
     assign registers[write_reg] = write_data;
```

I have a 32-bit input write_data , which i want to an assign corresponding index which i get from write reg.Error says you cant do continuous assignment which i think causes by always@(*) but if i remove that

It says
object "registers" on left-hand side of assignment must have a net type
and its another error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "procedural assignment to a non-register result is not permitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472546/error-procedural-assignment-to-a-non-register-result-is-not-permitted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assign` *inside* an always block is the `procedural assignment`. It is **not** synthesizable and should not be used. It is there for very special modeling cases.

`continuous assignment`, or `assign` *outside* the always block is there for connecting `nets` and used all over the places. lhs of such an assignment must be a *net* type, i.e. *wire*. it cannot be a reg.

On the other hand all lhs in *always* blocks must be of 'reg' type.

what you had to do in your case was to remove the keyword *assign*:

```
input [31:0] write_data;
input [4:0]  write_reg;
reg [31:0] registers [31:0];

always @(*) 
     registers[write_reg] = write_data;
```

Comment: What is a practical use-case for procedural assign statements?  I swear I've never run into one myself.  Feels like it should be deprecated on account of being an exceptionally attractive nuisance for beginners judging by how often the problem pops up here.

Comment: @BrianMagnuson I am not really sure. I saw it only once in my practice used in gls simulation to work around some  initialization problems. It was used incorrectly in any case and caused headache to debug the issues it 
 itself introduced. I guess it could be used in some cells to model very specific electrical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronously assign to registers. Because the synthesizer parses it and routes to a physical register (i.e. flip-flop)

```
always @(posedge clk) 
    my_reg = my_data;
```

[image: A d-flip flop]